# FSL installation seems successful but fsl missing

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, xlaunch

I'm absolutely new to FSL and am trying to install it (the newest version, which I got from here: https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsldownloads_registration), following all the steps from the FSL website installation guide for Windows 10: https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Windows. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 running on Windows 10 and XLaunch (of VcXsrv).

At the end of the installation, it seemed that FSL was installed successfully and I could run `fslmaths` and get the information of the function. However, when I try to run `fsl`, I get the following error:

```
application-specific initialization failed: couldn't connect to display "172.30.16.1:0"
Error in startup script: couldn't connect to display "172.30.16.1:0"
    while executing
"load /home/lpzzi/fsl/lib/libtk8.6.so"
    ("package ifneeded Tk 8.6.12" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Tk"
    (file "/home/lpzzi/fsl/tcl/fslstart.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source [ file dirname [ info script ] ]/fslstart.tcl"
    (file "/home/lpzzi/fsl/tcl/fsl.tcl" line 71)
    invoked from within
"source ${FSLDIR}/tcl/${origname}.tcl"
    (file "/home/lpzzi/fsl/bin/fsl" line 20)
```

In addition, I also tried `fsleyes` and get exactly nothing happening:

```
<user>:~$ fsleyes
<user>:~$
```

So, it seems that some features are there, while others not. I read around the internet that it might not have installed properly and decided to try and uninstall it. So what I did was running:

```
sudo apt-get remove fsl 
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fsl 
sudo apt-get purge fsl 
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove fsl
```

After every command the report was that 0 files were changed/removed (i.e., it appears FSL was not there at all). When I try to access the directory where I presumably installed it, I get an error message that it's non-existant. However, after all this, I can still run `fslmaths` and get the options list of that function.

Another issue I have is with the DISPLAY setting. When I open the VCXsrv log file, I see somewhere the following:

```
LoadPreferences: Loading C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\system.XWinrc
(II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
(II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:2.0
winClipboardProc - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
Using Composite redirection
```

I've no idea what the display should be set to and I tried changing the current setting in Ubuntu as `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:2.0`. When I ran `echo $DISPLAY`, I could see it had changed but I still couldn't run any of the above two functions.

I realise there's probably more than one issue ongoing with this but any help/direction on where to start from would be highly appreciated.